# Binding a string to the tooltip of a button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having problems with binding `string`s.
When I maximize my window the tooltip of the button should change to "minimize" and if it is at normal size, the tooltip will be "enlarged".

This is my XAML code:

```
<Button Command="{Binding MaxWindowCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ucControlBar}"
        Background="ForestGreen"
        ToolTip="{Binding StateMinMax}"
        ToolBar.OverflowMode="AsNeeded">
   <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="WindowMaximize" />
</Button>
```

This is my code-behind:

```
public string StateMinMax { get; set; }
```

```
if (w != null)
{
   if(w.WindowState != WindowState.Maximized)
   {
      w.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
      StateMinMax = "min";
   }
   else
   {
      w.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
      StateMinMax = "max";
   }
}
```

I hope someone will help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: try using a [converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a style that sets the `ToolTip`. The first setter will set the default `ToolTip` *Minimize*, while the `DataTrigger` binds to the `WindowState` property of the containing `Window` that is searched up the visual tree using a `RelativeSource` binding. If the `WindowState` property changes to `Maximized`, then the trigger will change the `ToolTip` accordingly to *Enlarge*.

```
<Button Command="{Binding MaxWindowCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ucControlBar}"
        Background="ForestGreen"
        ToolBar.OverflowMode="AsNeeded">
   <Button.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
         <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Minimize"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="{x:Static WindowState.Maximized}">
               <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Enlarge"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Button.Style>
   <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="WindowMaximize"/>
</Button>
```

This is a XAML-only solution, so you do not need the `StateMinMax` property and code-behind.